# pytest: rollback between tests using SQLAlchemy and FastAPI

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pytest, fastapi

I have a FastAPI application where I have several tests written with pytest.

Two particular tests are causing me issues. `test_a` calls a post endpoint that creates a new entry into the database. `test_b` gets these entries. `test_b` is including the created entry from `test_a`. **This is not desired behaviour**.

When I run the test individually (using VS Code's testing tab) it runs fine. However when running all the tests together and `test_a` runs before `test_b`, `test_b` fails.

My `conftest.py` looks like this:

```py
import pytest
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from sqlmodel import Session, SQLModel, create_engine

from application.core.config import get_database_uri
from application.core.db import get_db
from application.main import app


@pytest.fixture(scope="module", name="engine")
def fixture_engine():
    engine = create_engine(
        get_database_uri(uri="postgresql://user:secret@localhost:5432/mydb")
    )
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
    yield engine
    SQLModel.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="db")
def fixture_db(engine):
    connection = engine.connect()
    transaction = connection.begin()
    session = Session(bind=connection)
    yield session
    session.close()
    transaction.rollback()
    connection.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="function", name="client")
def fixture_client(db):
    app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = lambda: db
    with TestClient(app) as client:
        yield client
```

The file containing `test_a` and `test_b` also has a module-scoped pytest fixture that seeds the data using the `engine` fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
def seed(engine):
    connection = test_db_engine.connect()
    seed_data_session = Session(bind=connection)
    seed_data(seed_data_session)
    yield
    seed_data_session.rollback()
```

All tests use the `client` fixture, like so:

```py
def test_a(client):
    ...
```

SQLAlchemy version is 1.4.41, FastAPI version is 0.78.0, and pytest version is 7.1.3.

#### My Observations

It seems the reason tests run fine on their own is due to `SQLModel.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)` being called at the end of testing. However I would like to avoid having to do this, and instead only use rollback between tests.

Comment: Should not you yield transaction from fixture_db instead of session? And it's better to use context manager protocol here also.

Comment: I did a similar setup following this [blog post](https://dev.to/jbrocher/fastapi-testing-a-database-5ao5).

Answer (score 0):

What worked really well for me is using testcontainers: https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-python.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module", name="session_for_db_in_testcontainer")
def db_engine():
    """
    Creates testcontainer with Postgres db
    """
    pg_container = PostgresContainer('postgres:latest')
    pg_container.start()

    # Fireup the SQLModel engine with the uri of the container
    db_engine = create_engine(pg_container.get_connection_url())
    sqlmodel_metadata.create_all(db_engine)

    with Session(db_engine) as session_for_db_in_testcontainer:
        # add some rows to start, for test get requests and posting existing data
        add_data_to_test_db(database_input_path, session_for_db_in_testcontainer)
        yield session_for_db_in_testcontainer

    # Will be executed after the last test
    session_for_db_in_testcontainer.close()
    pg_container.stop()
```

Like this during the test run a (Postgres) DB is created it only runs during a session, module or function depending on the scope of the fixture. If you want, you can add test data to the db as well like in the example.

In your case you might want to set the scope of this fixture as function. Than `test_a` and `test_b` should run independently.